# IOS Swift- UITbar setting custom tabbar height leaves empty Space above it

Tags: ios, swift, tabbar

I would like to know if there is a way to remove the empty space above the tab bar. I using below code in the custom class of UITabBarController.

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    var tabFrame = self.tabBar.frame
    tabFrame.size.height = 50
    tabFrame.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height - 40
    self.tabBar.frame = tabFrame

}
```

The resulting image looks like this. There is black empty space above the tab bar. Kindly let me know if i can remove the empty space.
Thank you

[image]